# Weird space before images when placed in Bootstrap Columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create an image gallery in which three images are placed in a row of 4-columns each such that there is no white space between them and they touch. 
But in doing so, there is some weird white space at the left side of each image in each column.

Take a look here: http://www.bootply.com/IQMBlg5q9L

Comment: Please try this code this code will work perfectly without adding any extra classes than bootstrap. The second answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.no-gutters` is not a built in Bootstrap class. To use it you need to add the required CSS it references yourself. For example:

```
img { max-width: 100%;}

.row.no-gutters {
   margin-right: 0;
   margin-left: 0;
}

.row.no-gutters > [class^="col-"], .row.no-gutters > [class*=" col-"] {
   padding-right: 0;
   padding-left: 0;
}
```

In the following snippet I replaced your "md" cols with "xs" and reduced the images size, just so it doesn't collapse in the viewing window here:

```css
img { max-width: 100%;}

.row.no-gutters {
   margin-right: 0;
   margin-left: 0;
}

.row.no-gutters > [class^="col-"], .row.no-gutters > [class*=" col-"] {
   padding-right: 0;
   padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="portfolio-main">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/250x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/250x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/250x150">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But there is still that little white space to the left of first image and to the right of the second one even though the container is fluid. How can I fix that?

Comment: Adding ..container-fluid {padding: 0px !important} would do it. Although you might want to also simply remove the container.

Comment: Hey, can you tell me why is it happening? I thought that container-fluid spans the entire available width! Is it not the case?

Comment: It would do ordinarily, because the 15px of padding on the container would be "retaken" by the row's -15px of negative margin. But the "no-gutters" is interfering with the normal structure.

Comment: You could also experiment with removing the second block: .row.no-gutters {
   margin-right: 0;
   margin-left: 0;
} This would make the container (seem!) to have no padding again I think

Comment: Is it ok for you now? :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for adding extra classes for space issue in bootstrap. for removing spacing issue you can use class row

```
<div id="portfolio-main">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                          <div class="row">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/350x150">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/350x150">
                              </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="row">
                             <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/350x150">
                             </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```